# Realistic Glass Shader

Tags: shaders, glass, hdri

I have building with glass facade in urban setting lit with hdri and I am trying to do a photomontage with the rendered building.

Screenshot
1: my glass shader
2: glass with reflections from the surrounding model buildings (basic extrusions with no material)
3: glass without surround model
4: desired glass look (examples)

The issue I have is that I don't get the reflections from the HDRI and the glass looks dark and gray (3). More realistic look is achived with the reflections from the surround model (2) but the issue I have here is that reflections are visible from the model which is not the real environment.

Can someone help me achive realistic curtain wall glass?
Idk if the issue is due to my glass shader or the lighting.[image]

Comment: There are several(!) good glass materials supplied with the [Material Library VX](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/materials/material_library.html) add-on (Basic, sheet, Facade, Fake). These provide good starting points that you can then edit to your liking, for example to create tints and  the like).